# Why inserting dataframe into TimescaleDb takes longer than into MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, postgresql, sql-insert, timescaledb

i am tring to understand why inserting 2 Million rows into TimescaleDB/PostgreSQL takes longer than inserting them into mysql, because TimescaleDB is said to have high insert rates, higher than mysql...

Used the folling:

MySQL:

```
engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://root:paswd@localhost/db")
con = engine.connect()
readcsv = pd.read_csv(r"C:\2mio.csv",delimiter=',',names=['x','y'],skiprows=1 )
a=1 
readcsv.insert(2,"z",a)
readcsv.to_sql(name='table',con=con,schema='db',if_exists='append',index=False)
```

Duration: 500seconds

PostgrSQL/TimescaleDb:

```
engine = create_engine("postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:paswd@127.0.0.1/postgres")
con = engine.connect()
readcsv = pd.read_csv(r"C:\2mio.csv",delimiter=',',names=['x','y'],skiprows=1)
a=1 
readcsv.insert(2,"z",a)
readcsv.to_sql(name='table',con=con,schema='postgres',if_exists='append',index=False)
```

Duration 870 seconds

Answer (score 2):

Your bottleneck here is likely your python library.

You are seeing something like 2-4K rows per second.  Well-tuned TimescaleDB with parallel ingest and insert batching will do 100-300K rows / second.  And at a total of 2M-row DB, you aren't testing ingest at scale (starts appearing in billions of rows).

Cheers.